# Is there an easier way to show/hide an element on a mouse action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, live

I have this segment of code here, which I seem to use something similar all the time:

```
$(".fieldv").live('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).children('.edit-icon').show();
}).live('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).children('.edit-icon').hide();
});
```

Is there an easier, simpler, or cleaner way to show / hide an element on a mouse action whether it be hovering or clicking an element? Or something of the like...

Comment: There are already appropriate answers here. As for your method of choice (.live()), depending on the version of jQuery you're using, you may want to use .delegate() (<1.7) or .on() (>=1.7) instead of .live() and similar events in other parts of your code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why use JavaScript?

You will need to hide the icon by default:

```
.fieldv .edit-icon { display: none; }
```

Then this CSS applies on hover (and ONLY on hover)

```
.fieldv:hover .edit-icon { display: block; /* or inline, etc. */ }
```

Comment: Was about to post this. +1

Comment: +1 You shouldn't assume `block`, but this is a much better approach.

Comment: @JonathanSampson Yeah, had that thought as I typed it. Clarification added. Thx. (Of course his example would have used `block` and `none` via jQuery.)

Comment: I would, but I need to hide the element when I mouseout

Comment: How can you hover over a hidden element?

Comment: @Musa Crap. Mistake in code added for clarification. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
       $(".fieldv").hover(function(){

              //mouseover

       ,function(){

              //mouseout
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".fieldv").hover(function() {
        $(this).children('.edit-icon').show();
    }, function() {
        $(this).children('.edit-icon').hide();
 });
```

use $(".class").hover(function(){}, function(){});

Comment: also you can't use delegation with `.hover()`